# Remove residues blender

Tags: modeling

I would like to know how to remove residues in a blender project? I'm a beginner, and often there are loose ends that don't want to go away... thank you in advance..

[image]

Comment: I don't think there's any automatic way to remove automatically the residues you show because Blender can't guess that they are residues, the best is to not create them

Comment: Please don't post photos of your computer screen. Blender has a built-in system fro producing images accessed from the Window > Save Screenshot menu.